# How to configure communication with arduino

Tags: rosserial-arduino, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to configure the communication using rosserial to arduino and to install everything.

I followed this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup
and am trying to finish this one http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World

Here is the error I am getting, I just cannot locate serial_node.py anywhere on my computer!

---

rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB0

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named serial_node.py below /opt/ros/indigo/share/rosserial_python

---

I couldn't find anyone having the same issue, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261216/how-to-configure-communication-with-arduino/) by [tomahawk077](https://answers.ros.org/users/30286/tomahawk077/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this issue, but now I cannot run helloworld for another reason:
sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/Esp8266Hardware.h:36:25: fatal error: ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

---

Originally posted by [tomahawk077](https://answers.ros.org/users/30286/tomahawk077/) with karma: 16 on 2017-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0